# Как составить правильную формулу расчета угла между векторами?

Tags: математика, геометрия, вектор

Есть стандартная формула расчета угла между векторами:

[image: Формула расчета угла между векторами]

И вот есть два вектора, угол между которыми никак не вычислить, так как правая часть уравнения меньше -1. Вот эти вектора:

```
var x1 = -0.045797169475341334, y1 = -0.9989507591808752;
var x2 = 0.04579716947534099, y2 = 0.9989507591808753;
```

В итоге, выражение:

```
(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1, 2) + Math.pow(y1, 2)) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2, 2) + Math.pow(y2, 2))
```

дает результат: **-1.0000000000000002**

И если взять арккосинус этого числа, то будет `NaN`, что и понятно, так как он определен на промежутке от `-1 до 1`.

Как мне скорректировать формулу, чтобы этой ошибки не было?

Comment: У Вас в исходной формуле в числителе модуль (абсолютное значение). В коде должен быть вызов функции `abs` для `x1 * x2 + y1 * y2`.

Comment: Ну, `abs` тут конечно не поможет. Можно банально вставить проверку типа `if (r>1 || r< -1) r = +-1` (псевдокод такой). По другому ошибки округления не поправить. Проще всего функцию `acos` переопределить - написать свою с проверкой выхода из диапазона `[-1, 1]`.

Comment: Или использовать с-шный `atan2`. Он не дает подобных ошибок.

Comment: Вообще, при угле между векторами, близком к Пи, возможны значительные ошибки, связанные именно с округлением.

Comment: @andy.37 Это как сделать с `atan2`?

Comment: Что-то типа `phi = atan2(y2, x2) - atan2(y1, x1)`. Ошибка будет возникать при "нулевом" векторе, но для такого и постановка вопроса некорректно, т. к. его угол неопределен. Думаю, в Java (или это C#) должно быть что-то подобное. Вообще, `atan2(y, x)` это `atan(y/x)` корректно работающий при x=0.

Comment: @andy.37: `atan2` не для угла между векторами

Comment: Вы можете повысить точность ваших вычислений, если вместо `Math.Pow` просто умножите число на себя.

Comment: @VladD, а что запрещает Вам вычесть один угол из другого?

Comment: @andy.37: Окей, согласен. Пишите ответ тогда. ([Math.Atan2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @andy.37 Почему `abs` не поможет? Насколько я вижу, минус здесь появляется не из-за округления а исключительно потому, что в формуле вместо модуля выражения берётся само выражение. То есть формула реализована с ошибкой.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, потому что `acos(1.0000..02)` даст ту же ошибку, что `acos(-1.0000...02)`. А `acos(1) == acos(-1)` с точностью 3.1415... А так Вы правы, формулу лучше реализовывать правильно)

Comment: @andy.37 Теперь сообразил, спасибо.

Comment: Почему я модуль опустил: с модулем функция определена на промежутке от 0 до 180 градусов. А мне нужно до 360 градусов, то есть полный круг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Варианта решения проблемы имеются как минимум 2. Оба они требует, чтобы оба вектора имели ненулевую длину, но для вектора с нулевой длиной сама постановка вопроса о каком-либо угле не вполне корректна, и как Вам обрабатывать такую ситуацию, Вам должно быть виднее.

1) вычисляем промежуточное значение:

```
r = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1, 2) + Math.pow(y1, 2)) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2, 2) + Math.pow(y2, 2))
```

Проверяем на попадание r в диапазон [-1, 1]:

```
if (r < -1) r = -1; if (r > 1) r = 1;
```

Вычисляем арккосинус. Так убираются ошибки округления, "выбивающие" r из диапазона.

2) Пользуемся функцией `atan2`

```
phi = Math.atan2(y2, x2) - Math.atan2(y1, x1);
```

При необходимости, приводим полученный угол в нужный диапазон (0-180град или -90 - +90)

---

Я бы написал так:

```
if (phi < 0) phi += Math.PI * 2;
if (phi > Math.Pi) phi -= Math.PI;
```

---

Оба алгоритма выдадут ошибку при x1=y1=0 или x2=y2=0, о чем написано выше.
Вариант с `atan2`, имхо предпочтительней, т.к., например при x1=y1=1e+10, x2=y2=1e-10 точность вычислений по первому варианту будет околонулевой (e10 взято просто для примера, м.б. нужно существенно больше).

---

Математические функции указаны для Java, для .NET названия содержат заглавную букву: `Math.Sqrt`, `Math.Atan2` и т. д.

Comment: В .NET функция называется `Math.Sqrt` (с большой буквы). А вместо `Pow` лучше умножать на себя вручную. Хотя, может у автора имеется в виду Java?

Comment: @VladD, я копировал код ТС, по причине полного незнания .NET и C#. Просто проблема тут не от языка зависит. Если можете поправить ответ с точки зрения синтаксиса C#, поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Готово, отредактировал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! atan2 мне больше понравился. Наверное его и буду использовать. По-мойму в варианте с atan2 нужно модуль вычислять. Отрицательный угол не нужен.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob хороший вопрос - нормальный ответ. Только не модуль. `atan2` возвращает значение в диапазоне [-pi, pi]. В результате, у Вас получится диапазон [-2*pi, 2*pi]. Его нужно нормализовать либо к диапазону [0, 2pi], либо к [-pi, pi], либо к [0, pi] (если порядок векторов неважен). Это несложно. Если нужно, допишу, но лучше ведь самому придумать?

Comment: у меня так получилось: `abs((atan2(y1, x1) + PI) - (atan2(y2, x2) + PI))`

Answer (score 0):

Если есть желание воспользоваться формулой для разности углов (а оно понятно из вопроса), то можно использовать тангенсы половинного аргумента с периодом 360: 
`phi = 2(Math.atan2(y2, x2+r2) - Math.atan2(y1, x1+r1));`

Проверим эту формулу на данных  **x1 = sqrt(3), y1=1, x2= - sqrt(3), y2=1 r1=r2=2:**
Правильный ответ: **cos(fi) = -1/2, fi=120**.
По формуле для разности:
**fi1=2arctg(1/(2+sqrt(3))) = 30, fi2=2arctg(1/(2-sqrt(3))=150, fi=fi2-fi1 = 120**.
Остаётся только преобразовать интервал, на выбор:
 либо **mod(fi,360)**, либо **mod(fi+180,360)-180**

В то же время:

1. Модуль нужно убрать, потому что его нет в теории.
2. Тангенсы в чистом виде лучше не использовать, потому что есть риск ошибки.
   Так, для тех же данных по формуле
   `phi = (Math.atan2(y2, x2) - Math.atan2(y1, x1);`
   имеем:
   **fi = arctg(sqrt(-3)) - arctg(sqrt(3)) = -120.**
   Парадокс объясняется тем, что тангенс имеет период 180, а
   **сos(fi+180) = cos(fi)cos(180)+sin(fi)sin(180) = - cos(fi)**.

Comment: странно, но пока путаницы нет же

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Я уточнил ответ.